# Can't mount fdescfs to /dev/fd

Tags: kernel, mount, freebsd, dmesg

Hello I can't mount fdesc,here is the output

```
root@nshost2:~ # mount -t fdescfs fdesc /dev/fd
mount: fdesc: Operation not supported by device
```

And here is the output of `dmesg`

```
root@nshost2:~ # dmesg | grep fdesc
KLD fdescfs.ko: depends on kernel - not available or version mismatch
```

And `kldstat` output

```
root@nshost2:~ # kldstat
Id Refs Address            Size     Name
 1   22 0xffffffff80200000 1755638  kernel
 2    1 0xffffffff81956000 11958    carp.ko
 3    1 0xffffffff81968000 5e578    if_bce.ko
 4    1 0xffffffff819c7000 14810    if_lagg.ko
 5    1 0xffffffff81c11000 357e     ums.ko
 6    3 0xffffffff81c15000 32efe    pf.ko
 7    1 0xffffffff81c48000 807e     pfsync.ko
 8    1 0xffffffff81c51000 26c5     pflog.ko
 9    1 0xffffffff81c54000 6381     nullfs.ko
```

Comment: What version of FreeBSD is that? How did you install it? Are you running the official kernel binary?

Comment: Hello Gilles, thank you for answer.

10.1, there is a GENERIC kernel.It was installed several years ago.

Here is output of uname:

Code:
FreeBSD nshost2.ucom.am 10.1-RELEASE-p19 FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE-p19 #0: Sat Aug 22 03:55:09 UTC 2015     root@amd64-builder.daemonology.net:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64

Comment: Did you maybe update the kernel but not reboot? Check what kernel version is installed (I don't know how to do it on FreeBSD) and compare with the `uname` output (which tells you what version is running).